# как открыть play market в приложении созданном с помощью phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap

Подскажите, как можно открыть приложение в play market. Приложение писал с помощью pgonegap. Пробовал a href="market://details?id=com.YOUR.PACKAGENAME" data-role='button'> Кнопка a> и обычную прямую ссылку вставлять на сайт. В первом случае ничего не происходит, во втором не дает открыть.

Comment: window.open("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.YOUR.PACKAGENAME")

Comment: в общем я сделал с помощью вот этого плагина [https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market](https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market)

Comment: Опишите в ответе, вопрос хороший.